# How should mouse events be rotated for HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating a web application with HTML canvas. Users can add, move, and rotate rectangles. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble interpreting mouse events after a shape has been rotated. How can I "rotate" a given x/y along with the shape?

Rectangles are drawn as follows:

```
context.translate(centerX, centerY);
context.rotate(radians);
context.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

Suppose the user clicks on (x, y). I need to transform this point into something relative to the rectangle. I've tried the inverse transformation to what the shape experiences.

```
// Opposite of `translate(centerX, centerY)`;
let xPrime = x - centerX;
let yPrime = y - centerY;
// Opposite of `rotate(radians)`;
xPrime = xPrime * Math.cos(-radians) - yPrime * Math.sin(-radians);
yPrime = xPrime * Math.sin(-radians) + yPrime * Math.cos(-radians);
// Opposite of `translate(-centerX, -centerY)`;
xPrime = xPrime + centerX;
yPrime = yPrime + centerY;
```

But sadly, this doesn't supply the correct numbers.

Comment: Possible for you to create a working example of what you have? You can use the stackoverflow snippet or maybe create a [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) having a working demo to work with is easier to debug and fix which will help provide a better answer/solution. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/pzueaogn/. Try clicking and dragging the shape. Things work nicely when `rotationDegrees` is set to 0. But any other value (say 20) makes the mouse event have an incorrect x/y.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by incorrect x/y. I cam able to drag with left and right click with the same result when `rotationDegrees` is set to **0** and **20**  [**JsFiddle with rotationDegrees=20**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/sjbu9xqg/) **Edit:** The only time I can make the cursor move into a incorrect position is when I zoom in on the browser  using `CTRL` & `+` are you sure you have your browser zoom to 100%?

Comment: @NewToJS The x/y is only slighly incorrect. Try clicking and dragging in this location: ![click](https://i.ibb.co/RNg7Cy1/click.png)

Comment: Sorry I don't see it. I am using google Chrome, what browser are you using? Without me being able to reproduce the problem I cannot try find the reason & solution. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: @NewToJS Here's an example that makes the issue more obvious: https://jsfiddle.net/5as27pgb/. Try clicking and dragging in this specific location outside the shape: https://ibb.co/2hbFgWd

Comment: Do you mean you can click and drag the box outside of the filled section?

Comment: @NewToJS exactly! And this isn't the behavior I see when the shape is not rotated.

Comment: you should edit your question with the examples in the comment...
on your  isTouching(x, y) you are not accounting for the square to be rotated... I think you should be using game framework for this